# I want To Convert Object To Integer or Float i'm trying since one day but i'm unable to find a solution please let me know the answer

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xW8O4.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3gaP.png)

Please go through the images.... sir
i have 4 columns which have object values like 1,254 , 1,256, 1,489.... like this.... and these are in the `Object` Format and i want to convert these values into `Int` but i'm getting an error like

> `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,259.11'`

please help me i'm trying since 1 day but i'm unable to get it please help me out

Comment: Do not use images for sample data or error message. Put it in text format so it would be easy to reproduce example for people.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you've got commas in the data, so pandas thinks it's a string. Try removing the commas then converting the column to a float:

```
temp["Close Price"] = temp["Close Price"].str.replace(",","")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) first to remove comma from string and then convert it to float.
Ex.:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',','').astype('float'))
         a        b
0  1259.11  1259.11
1  1257.63  1257.63
```

To apply on specific columns select columns using [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) or [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) so For you it would be

```
temp.iloc[:,1:5] = temp.iloc[:,1:5].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',','').astype('float'))
```